# Authenticating SoapUI requests with Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, active-directory, soapui, azure-ad-b2c, web-api-testing

We have a web application which uses Active Directory B2C for authentication. To do API testing we are planning to use SoapUI.

There are many requests that needs Authorization token to be send as a header in the request. So my plan is to **send an authentication request first get the cookies and send it in other requests as authorization header**.

So far I was not able to  find a way to do it in SoapUI. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First you can fire a get request on /authorize endpoint, get the authcode and then fire a post on /token endpoint

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code